# Where would a question about a Firefox extension be on topic?

Tags: discussion

[Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/) do not take questions about Firefox extensions, for the obvious reason that they're not about applications related to the web. It's about Web Applications, i.e. server-side.

Firefox is a desktop/client app rather than a server app.

They don't like them on Web Apps:

- [Reason for my question better suitable to superuser than here?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/804/reason-for-my-question-better-suitable-to-superuser-than-here)
- [colorzilla extension doesn't work in Firefox 12, Any good alternatives?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/27299/colorzilla-extension-doesnt-work-in-firefox-12-any-good-alternatives)

And they're getting closed on Super User too:

- [Any alternative to Universal Uploader (fireuploader) for Firefox?](https://superuser.com/questions/386757/any-alternative-to-universal-uploader-fireuploader-for-firefox)

Comment: The referenced question on [su] is not closed. Look before ranting.

Comment: I'm sorry, what's your point? What do you want to discuss?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't see what you're ranting about. (Yes I use rant because the comments on the question were rants).

- Questions on extensions are offtopic for WebApps.
- Questions on extensions are ontopic for Super User.
- Same constructive question guidelines holds good.
- The question you've referenced **is not** closed.

Repeat after me - close votes on a question does not mean a question is closed. The question was asked in Feb & is still not closed. What are you on about it being closed? Even if it's closed so what? You very well know there are plenty of recourses.

- You know as a 3k user you can vote to reopen
- You can flag to reopen
- You can ask a meta question
- You can drop a link into Chat

Closure is not a permanent state; it can and has been reversed several times. So coming back, I really don't know what you're ranting about.

Comment: Well spotted, so it has 2 votes to close..but is not yet closed. There seems to be a perception that it was off topic and was for webapps. I'd have commented that it was on topic then if I saw 2 votes to close and comments that it should be asked in webapps.  I thought you commented along the lines that it was off topic and should be asked in webapps, though your comment was removed so I can't see

Comment: The initial comment was "it belongs to WA", to which I replied "not it does not" and was acknowledged. I have no clue why you read only the first comment and went on that rant spree. @barlop

Comment: Looks like I erred a bit. A user's initial comment was completely absurd and silly,he wrote "As this is regarding the compatibility requirements of a website, I believe this question should be on the WebApps site. @music2myear "You answered him "looks like a request for an alternative addon in which case....".  for SU not Webapps.And I just saw a link to WebApps in your comment and the beginning of your comment,seemed like it was suggesting webapps. That and the 2 votes to close.I personally would've been clearer that the question is fine and that obviously it's not about website requirements

Comment: Plus when I said that firefox is a desktop application not a web app, you replied saying What are you talking about. So it sounded like you didn't agree with me.

Comment: What do you mean "You can drop a link into Chat"?  One can go into a chat and chat, but one can't really "drpp a link" on a question when it is deleted(as it was). I suppose you mean they can add a link which will be seen for as long as the question is not deleted.